# How do I enable 2/3 multisigs to approve the transaction before the admin cal call the withdraw method?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I have a function called `withdraw` in my code. I am using OpenZeppelin access control to limit access to approved managers. However for security reasons, I want two or more other admins to approve that transaction before the ether is sent to the owner's wallet. Is this possible?

Additional info:

- The `withdraw` method should be called by the manager but must be approved by the owner multisig
- Currently, the attached code doesn't go through the multisig
- I have tried contract interaction on gnosis safe, but it fails with a message of "this transaction will fail"

```
function withdraw() onlyRole(managerRole) nonReentrant public returns(bool) {
    (bool sent, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: getBalance()}("");
    require(sent, "Ether not sent: transaction failed");
    emit balanceWithdrawn(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the gnosis safe wallet is assigned the ```managerRole``` in the contract?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on Rinkeby? And then ignore the error and execute the tx  anyway?

Comment: It should be possible to create sign and execute a safe tx, that calls this withdraw function.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a bunch. I  needed to make gnosis safe the contract owner. it worked

Comment: @DirkJäckel I can only use Avalanche network cos I am interacting with another contract on avalanche. So it won't work on rinkeby

Comment: @EniolaAgboola awesome, glad it worked out.